# Cargar pdf y visualizarlo al instante

Tags: javascript, html5

Hola quiero poder cargar pdfs en mi pagina web, pero quiero saber si hay alguna forma de cargarlos desde mis archivos y visualizarlo.

Esta forma es la mas sencilla, pero el archivo ya debe estar en tu carpeta

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Visor de PDF</title>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="tu_archivo.pdf" width="100%" height="600px"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Y esta es la forma que probe, seleccionar mi archivo y subirlo, pero no funciona

```js
   
    <script>
        function cargarPDF() {
            var input = document.getElementById('pdfInput');
            var archivo = input.files[0];

            if (archivo) {
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('pdf', archivo);

                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('POST', 'cargar_pdf.php', true);

                xhr.onload = function () {
                    if (xhr.status === 200) {
                        // Éxito: Actualizar el visor con el nuevo PDF
                        var visorPDF = document.getElementById('pdfFrame');
                        visorPDF.src = xhr.responseText;
                    } else {
                        // Error: Manejar según sea necesario
                        console.error('Error al cargar el PDF');
                    }
                };

                xhr.send(formData);
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Puedes visualizar el PDF sin subirlo al servidor, a menos que requieres siempre que de igual manera se guarden en el servidor, es ese tu caso? . Además agrega el código `cargar_pdf.php`

Comment: *Cargarlos desde tus archivos*. ¿Te refieres a cargar archivos de tu equipo local, programaticamente desde una página web? Eso no es posible debido a la seguridad que implementa el navegador.